# Kafka docker container cannot run in virtual machine

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, virtual-machine, virtualbox, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to run [kafka docker image](https://github.com/ches/docker-kafka) inside my VirtualBox. I firstly run zookeeper server by:

```
 docker run -d -p 2181:2181 --name zookeeper jplock/zookeeper
```

After that, I run kafka which is linked to that zookeeper server:

```
docker run -d --name kafka --link zookeeper:zookeeper ches/kafka
```

When I check "docker ps -a", only zookeeper is running and kafka is not (the status of kafka is always "Exited".

[image: docker ps -a]

However, when I do those things above outside VM, which is local machine, everything work just fine. What am I missing here?

Update: I just run the "docker logs kafka" and I got this:

[image: docker logs kafka]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that VM did not have enough memory to allocate for kafka server. I got it from the last 3 bottom lines of the second picture above. And the solution is quite easy, I just need to assign bigger memory to VM in vagrantfile, previously it was 1024. And now:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vm|
    vm.memory = 2048
    vm.cpus = 2
```